# Show/hide div based on radio value (custom radios, Foundation 4)

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) for custom radio buttons.

My radio buttons look like this:

```
<label for="cat"><input name="cat" value="jersey" type="radio" id="jersey" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span></label>
<label for="cat"><input name="cat" value="shorts" type="radio" id="shorts" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span></label>
<label for="cat"><input name="cat" value="shirts" type="radio" id="shirts" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span></label>
```

My jquery looks like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('.area').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

The html that displays the div's look like this:

```
<div class='area' id="jersey">jersey</div>
<div class='area' id="shorts">shorts</div>
<div class='area' id="shirts">shirts</div>
<div class='area' id="reversible">reversible</div>
<div class='area' id="outerwear">outerwear</div>
<div class='area' id="helmets">helmets</div>
<div class='area' id="other">other</div>
```

It was previously working with normal radio buttons, but I have had no luck in getting it to work with these custom radio buttons. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Why are all the radio buttons set to `display:none;`?

Comment: It's because a `div` doesn't have a programmatic `val()` to calculate. Things like radios, inputs, and forms do. You can try `html()` instead of `val()`. Or try testing for the value of each `id`, like `$.attr("id")`

Comment: The inputs are replaced with custom elements, so you are no longer clicking the inputs, and that's why it does'nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique, jQuery only selects the first element with a specific ID, so you are trying to show the clicked input element which in fact is hidden and doesn't trigger the change/click event. You should listen to `click` event that is triggered by `span` elements.

```
$(function(){
    var $divs = $('.area');

    $('label').on('click', 'span.radio', function() {
        var val = $(this).prev('input').val();
        $divs.hide().filter('#' + val).show();  
    });
})
```

Comment: Even using this, it does not seem to want to select the div. The radio/span is selected, but the div does not appear.

Comment: @Alex Do you see any errors on the console? Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NbqnK/ Welp, it seems to work on jsfiddle! I'll go ahead and mark your answer correct. For whatever reason, it is NOT working on my website nor locally.